# Laravel exists validation doesn't work

Tags: laravel

Simply, I want to check that email exists in `user` table on database by this below code, but `exist` method in validation doesn't work correctly and I get a validation error as `This Email doesnt in table`

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    if (Validator::make($request->all(), ['email' => 'required|exists:users'])->fails()) {
        dd('This Email doesnt in table');
    }
}
```

result of `dd($request->all());` is :

```
array:2 [▼
  "email" => "pishguy@gmail.com"
]
```

my user table has `"pishguy@gmail.com"` email and i dont have problem

[image]

Comment: Are you sure there's a table called 'users' with a field called 'email' with value "pishguy@gmail.com" in your database?

Comment: @Amarnasan yes, post updated with screenshot

Answer (score -3):

```
$rules = array(
    'email' => 'required|email|exists:users,email'
);

$validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules);

if ($validator->fails()){
  echo " email does not exist";
}
```

This is the standard, better write it this way. Code is more readable.